# How to debug Rails Stimulus with Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, webpack, stimulusjs, jsbundling-rails

Rails 7, jsbundling-rails, webpack

A page using Stimulus gives a JavaScript error which in Chrome points to a compiles JavaScript. For me it would be more useful to have it point to the original Stimulus JavaScript.

Maybe I need to dig back into stack traces and the like.

For example, I'm now seeing `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.controllerConstructor.shouldLoad')`.